# Is bin(n)bin(2^(k+1) * n + 1)^R context free?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, pumping-lemma, pushdown-automaton

bin is shortest number in binary

Is bin(n)bin(2^(k+1) * n + 1)^R context free?

k,n belongs to natural numbers.

I know bin(n)bin(n + 1)^R is context free but I don't have idea how to solve  bin(n)bin(2^(k+1) * n + 1)^R . If is context-free can someone help me build context-free grammar?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `x^R` means `x` reversed, then you're looking for strings in the form

```
n1(many zeros)(n)^R
```

Since "many zeros" in this case is just `0*`, a regular expression, you can adapt whatever grammar you have for `n(n+1)^R` into this language and it will still be context free.

Let's look at n=5, k=2

```
n = 101
2^(k+1) = 2^3 = 1000
1000 * 101 is 101000
101000 + 1 is 101001
101001^R is 100101
```

The final string is

```
n1(zeroes)n^R
101100101
```

Comment: how will be look grammar context-free look like?

Comment: As this looks like a homework question, I will answer vaguely. The grammar will look very similar to grammars that match the language `ww^R`, except with `10*` between `w` and `w^R`.

Comment: add C-> C0 | 1 | to grammar from below website. Will be good? It isn't homework. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75890/context-free-grammar-for-binnbinn1r

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether the language `bin(n)bin(2^(k+1) * n + 1)^R` is context-free. I take `bin(n)` to mean the binary representation of the natural number `n` without any leading zeroes.

Suppose `bin(n') = x`. Here, `x` is a finite string of binary digits beginning with `1`. Let us determine what bin(2^(k+1) * n + 1) looks like. First, note that multiplying a number by two adds a zero to the end of that number's binary representation; just the same as multiplying by ten when using decimal. Multiplying by 2^(k+1) will add k+1 zeroes. Because k is a natural number, at least one zero must be added. Adding one to this number will flip the least significant bit over to 1 from 0. The end result is that `bin(2^(k+1) * n + 1) = x(0^k)1`.

The language `bin(n)bin(2^(k+1) * n + 1)^R` consists of strings of the form `x(x(0^k)1)^R`. We can distribute the `^R` by reversing each of the concatenated substrings and the order of concatenation to see that these strings are of the form `x1(0^k)(x^R)`. We notice the outermost component of these strings begin with an arbitrary binary string `x` and end with `x^R`; we can handle this with a context-free grammar in the same we can handle languages of palindromes. The innermost component is `1(0^k)`, which describes the regular language `10*`; we can certainly handle that in a CFG. A CFG that works is the following:

```
S := 0S0 | 1S1 | T
T := T0 | 1
```

The main insight in deriving this is in determining the form of `(bin(2^(k+1) * x + 1)^R`.